# Prevent Content Scripts Running on My Web Page

Tags: javascript, browser-extension

I want to prevent my web page from been accessed by browser extension based content scripts. Are there any javascript frameworks / practices that could possible help me achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Everything I've seen says this is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really. Even if you write your own browser to try and prevent it, if it supports extensions the user can extend it. Also, it would be completely against the spirit of the web and maybe against the law. The user owns their computer, you can get in legally murky areas if you do things to a user's "browser".